# c-concavity and c-transform

Tags: convex-analysis, optimal-transport

I am having trouble in understanding $c$-concavity and the $c$-transform from Villani's book on optimal transport. Let $c:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be a cost function and $\psi:X\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. The $c$ transform $\psi $ is defined as $$\psi^c(y) = \inf\limits_{x\in X}(\psi(x)+c(x,y))$$ which is a generalisation of the Legendre transform when taking a cost $c(x,y)=-\langle x,y\rangle$. Indeed, with this cost we get $$\psi^c(x)=\sup\limits_{x\in X} (\langle x,y\rangle-\psi(x)).$$ But now a function $\phi$ is said to be $c$-concave if there exists $\psi$ such that $\phi=\psi^c$. But if we take again the cost $c(x,y)=-\langle x,y\rangle$ this means that $\phi$ is the Legendre transform of $\psi$, so $\phi$ should be convex not concave no?

Comment: There should be a negative sign in front of you $\sup$.

Comment: @Tobsn, thank you, but then $\psi^c$ is not even the Legendre transform when taking the particular cost $c(x,y)=-\langle x, y\rangle$ right?

Comment: It seems weird because it is written "If $c(x, y) = −x · y$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ , then the $c$-transform coincides with
the usual Legendre transform, and $c$-convexity is just plain convexity on $\mathbb{R}^n$"

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**
Your formula for $\psi^{c}$ for the cost described has the wrong sign.
Indeed, it should be convex, not concave.

---

Right after definition 5.2 in Cedric Villani's [*Optimal transport: old and new*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71050-9), which you are seemingly referring to, it says:

> If $c \colon \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, $(x, y) \mapsto - x \cdot y$, then [...] $c$-convexity is equivalent to plain convexity plus lower semicontinuity.

We prove this fact.

"$\implies$":
Suppose $\psi \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ is proper, convex and lower semicontinuous.
By the [Fenchel-Moreau-Rockafellar theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%E2%80%93Moreau_theorem), we have that the biconjugate (the Legendre transform of the Legendre transform) $\psi^{**} \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ of $\psi$ coincides with $\psi$.
Hence for the **negative of the** conjugate / Legendre transform $\zeta := - \psi^* \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ of $\psi$ we have
$$
\sup_{y \in \mathbb R^n} \zeta(y) - c(x, y)
= \sup_{y \in \mathbb R^n} x \cdot y - \psi^*(y)
= \psi^{**}(x)
= \psi(x)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
Hence $\psi$ is $c$-convex.

"$\impliedby$":
Suppose that $\psi \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ is $c$-convex for the above defined $c$.
By definition, this means that $\psi$ is proper and that there exists a function $\zeta \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ such that
$$
\psi(x)
= \sup_{y \in \mathbb R^n} \zeta(y) + x \cdot y.
$$
Hence $\psi$ is the pointwise supremum of the affine functions $f_y \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, $x \mapsto \zeta(y) + x \cdot y$.
In many (introductory) books on Convex Analysis (e.g. Rockafellar, Bauschke-Combettes, Ekeland-Temam) you will find the statement that the pointwise supremum of affine functions is convex and lower semicontinuous.

---

We see that the Legendre transform is *not* the same as the $c$-transform. In fact for the cost discussed in this answer we have that $\psi^{c} = (- \psi)^*$, where the star denotes the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Definition) / [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Definition).

**Definition** *([Proper function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_convex_function)).*
Let $X$ be a set.
A function $f \colon X \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ is proper if $f(x) > - \infty$ for all $x \in X$ and $\{ x \in X: f(x) < \infty \}$ is non-empty.